# IF-ELSE iteration: String.contains() fails each time

Tags: java, if-statement

I just want it to iterate through my arraylist and display once if user is not found, or once if user is found.

My code is working fine.

Just that lets take it as my users.txt have 3 users.

```
username:password:number
test1:pass1:123
test2:pass2:456
test3:pass3:789
```

So when I use this code and iterate through my arraylist

```
for (Users u: userDetails) {
    if (!u.getUser().toLowerCase().contains(userName.toLowerCase())) {
        System.out.println("Does not exist");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Exist");
    }
}
```

The above code is repeating 3 times "Does not exist" if i enter an invalid username. Anyone can enlighten me on this?

Comment: what is your question ?

Comment: What did the debugger say? Are the values contained?

Comment: What is the value of `userName`?

Comment: value of userName will be input by the user who is going to login. i.e asd or abc or test1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a *flag* variable:

```
boolean userExists = false; // flag

for (Users u: userDetails) {
    if (u.getUser().toLowerCase().contains(userName.toLowerCase())) {
        System.out.println("Exist");
        userExists = true; // update flag
    }
}

// check if user doesn't exist
if (!userExists)
    System.out.println("Does not exist");
```

Answer (score 3):

You may try it like this:

```
public static void checkUserExistence(Collection<Users> userDetails) {
    for (Users u: userDetails) {
        if (u.getUser().toLowerCase().contains(userName.toLowerCase())) {
            System.out.println("Exist");
            return;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Does not exist");
}
```

Comment: The second `System.out.println()` statement were at the wrong line. I did the edit on the fly, sorry. Now it should be corrected.